# Can't create new directory on shinyapp.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

On the shinyapp.io log, I get an error saying it cannot create dir

This works fine locally:

```
datetime <- format(Sys.time(),"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
dir.create(file.path("tmp", paste0("_", datetime)))
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.
Folder structure is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After further testing; I added `recursive=TRUE`and it worked on shinyapp.io. My guess is that the `tmp` folder is empty when I deploy, and shinyapp.io cannot recognize empty folders.

`dir.create(file.path("tmp", paste0("_", datetime)), recursive = TRUE)`